# Get type of generic from type

Tags: typescript, pdf.js

I got return type from method but need the type of the generic of that type.
I use method `getDocument` which return interface `PDFPromise<T>` and I need type of that `T` which is `PDFDocumentProxy`. I try:

```
type MyPDFPromise = ReturnType<typeof getDocument>; //get the PDFPromise<PDFDocumentProxy>
type MyPDFDocumentProxy = MyPDFPromise extends Promise<infer U> ? U : undefined;
```

But of course the `PDFPromise` don’t extend the `Promise`, I try with `Object` but with no luck. How could I get the type `PDFDocumentProxy` from that generic?

Thanks

Comment: It should be extending `PDFPromise<>`, not `Promise<>`.

Comment: Probably I don't understand something but I have the `MyPDFPromise` but not `MyPDFPromise<T>`. When I change the type to that with generic it still not working. I checked that suggested duplicate page but they creating the type not getting from function.

Comment: `MyPDFPromise` is an alias to the type `PDFPromise<PDFDocumentProxy>`. The second line is using pattern matching to determine the type of `U`. `PDFPromise<PDFDocumentProxy>` does not extend `Promise<U>`, but it does `PDFPromise<U>`. To which the compiler could infer the type `U = PDFDocumentProxy`.

Comment: Yes but I dont have the type `PDFPromise<U>`. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: It has to be a type known to the compiler. If you cannot get that type, you won't be able to extract from it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I could get it from the type.